# Expression for series using odd terms of series representation of Bessel function of the first kind?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebraic-number-theory, bessel-functions

We know:

$$_()=∑_{=0}^∞\frac{(−1)^}{Γ(++1)!}\bigr(\frac{}{2}\bigl)^{2+}\  (.1)$$
$$.. (,)∈ℕ,∈ℝ$$

Where $z>>1$

courtesy of WolframAlpha's entry on Bessel functions and that there are quite a few ways of approximating Bessel functions of the first kind (written above) asymptotically. To move on, if we take =1, then:
$$_1()=∑_{=0}^∞\frac{(−1)^}{Γ(+2)!}\bigr(\frac{}{2}\bigl)^{2+1}\    (. 2)$$
But I am interested in approximations for a series composed of the odd terms of the series representation above, $(.2)$: namely $∈ℕ$.

$$???=∑_{=0}^∞\frac{(−1)^{2k+1}}{Γ(2+3)(2k+1)!}\bigr(\frac{}{2}\bigl)^{4+3}\    (. 3)$$
Someone has suggested: [Mittag-Leffler functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_summation) in another question but I believe they missed the second factorial in the denominator of the series representation.

Comment: Approximate in what way/sense?  For instance, you could just truncate your series...

Comment: @EricTowers Truncation wouldn't accomplish a whole lot here, as you have to be careful where you do it in order to get manageable error terms. I was hoping for the odd terms to form a series which was equivalent to another known series which has known asymptotic expressions. The same way that the series formed from the even and odd terms can be approximated as $z$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: You have not responded to my question.  Do you want to control absolute error? relative error? large $z$? small $z$?  Your use of "approximation" is too imprecise to yield an answer.

Comment: @Eric Towers This is for arguments of large $z$, we are controlling for absolute error.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(−1)^{2k+1}}{\Gamma(2+3)(2k+1)!}\left(\frac{}{2}\right)^{4+3}= \frac{J_1(z)-I_1(z)}{2} $$

Answer (score 0):

Let \begin{align*}
f(K,z) = \mathrm{sgn}(z)\sum_{k=0}^K \frac{−1}{(2k+2)\Gamma(2k+2)^2} \left(\frac{|z|}{2} \right)^{4k+3}
\end{align*}

Your series is 
$$  f(\infty,z) = \frac{1}{2} (J_1(z)-I_1(z))$$  where $J$ and $I$ are the [Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1) and the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1), respectively.

For real arguments, the relative error in 
$$  f(\max(\{10,\lfloor z/3 \rfloor\}),z)  $$
is less than $0.02$ (i.e., ${}<2\%$).  If you replace "$z/3$" with "$z/2$", the relative error is bounded by $4 \times 10^{-6}$.